# Getting error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, datetime-parsing

Getting error like :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I am using this code :

```
string datetime = DateTime.Parse(encrypt[1]);
```

or

```
string datetime = Convert.ToDatetime(encrypt[1]);
```

**encrypt is a string array**

In `encrypt[1]` I am `not sure which format will come in string`. i have trace some time come `dd/MM/yyyy` and sometime `MM/dd/yyyy` or  `MM-dd-yyyy` or `dd-MM-yyyy`. I am not sure about format it may from above or another format come.

also use `ParseExcept` and `TryParseExcept`. but not get succeeded seems return same error

please give me proper solution.

Comment: You should know string format for parsing. Otherwise, you not be able to distinguish different dates. Example: string "01/02/2014" can be resolve to 01 Feb 2014 or 02 Jan 2014.

Comment: I am giving you my idea see: i have make one winform app and use for  create key using datetime and then i had give this app to client and client said not working on decryption then i am found its datetime formate issue. so we dont know which formate will be used my client.

Comment: You set tag asp.net mvc. When client post data from winform app, he post it to controller or api? If so, you can try get culture info from request. Other opportunity, if you can change winform app set culture there, one for all clients.

Answer (score 6):

AndreyAkinshin already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061880/getting-error-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-in-c-sharp#comment42637958_27061880) the real problem. I want to add this as an answer if he lets me..

Both `DateTime.Parse` and `Convert.ToDatetime` methods uses your `CurrentCulture` settings by default.

And your `CurrentCulture` can have **only** one of `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` format. It can't have both formats as a standard date and time format because it *can't* know which format it uses when you get a string like `01/01/2014`.

None of DateTime methods can solve your problem. Even if you use [`DateTime.TryParseExact` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes formats as a `string[]`, it parses your string with first successful format that matches in your array.

**tl;dr**

You *have to* know which format of your data has.

Comment: I am giving you my idea see: i have make one winform app and use for create key using datetime and then i had give this app to client and client said not working on decryption then i am found its datetime formate issue. so we dont know which formate will be used my client.

Comment: In that case, you need to adjust the code in the Winforms app to force an invariant date format.  For example, force the Winforms application to use ISO 8601 date format, which is unambiguous: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Answer (score 1):

If you don't exactly know what is coming in, you have **virtually no change of getting the date format in correctly**.

Take this sample:

```
01/02/2014
```

Is this the 2nd of January or the 1st of February?

If you *do* know the formats, you could use `TryParseExact` and just walk down the list until one matches:

```
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(encrypt[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{ }
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(encrypt[1], "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell programatically whether the date is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy unless they are obviously invalid, e.g. if you're expecting dd/mm/yyyy and you get 12/14/2014, then that format can only be mm/dd/yyyy.

However, since you are receiving the data from a HTTP request (question is tagged with MVC), you can find the user's culture and use that to parse the date using, e.g.

```
DateTime.Parse("13/12/2014", new CultureInfo("en-GB")); // Works fine.

DateTime.Parse("13/12/2014", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882561(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.